# Magento 2 : product is adding twice when disable add to cart ajax

Tags: magento2, php

When I disable the add to cart through ajax

> Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart

the user can click multiple times on the add to cart button on products pages (before to be redirected to cart) and it's adding the product multiple times to its cart.

Is there any way to fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: can you please tell me your magento version?

Answer (score 0):

As I Checked **"amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module"** Module Creating issue with Checkout.

Can you please once Disable this module and Check following.

Hope this will help You!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Steps:-

Disable the modules in Magento, by running this command:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Core Amazon_Login Amazon_Payment
```

Then

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento ca:cl
php bin/magento ca:fl
```

Hope this will help you..!